# Connecting Samsung 1080p Monitor to 2014 MDP via HDMI/Mini-DisplayPort

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

This question is related to [Unable to connect display(s) to MBP 13'' Mid 2014 via Tunderbolt / mini DisplayPort](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269302/unable-to-connect-displays-to-mbp-13-mid-2014-via-tunderbolt-mini-displayp), albeit with a different monitor that may have a different cause. As per the question above, I have already attempted SMC/NVRAM resets, and force-detecting the display.

I am attempting to connect a Samsung S24R650F monitor to a mid-2014 MBP as follows:

**MBP 2014 or MBP 2015 --> MBP Thunderbolt 2 Port --> mDP/HDMI Adaptor --> HDMI cable --> Samsung S24R650F**

I tested this successfully with different (lower res) monitors and TVs to isolate the problem as being the S24R650F monitor. I have also tested it against 2 identical, new S24R650 monitors, and the behaviour is identical on both: only S24R650F monitors do not detect the MBP, and the MBP does not detect the monitor in either `System Preferences` or `System Report`

Taking it a step further, I have also tried it with a second MBP (2015 i.e. a year newer) with no success. A further development was that I booted into Windows (Bootcamp), again with no success.

The only indication that the monitor is present is that the screen freezes every 5s for 1s - otherwise there is no signal at both ends. If I plug the HDMI cable directly into the MBP HDMI slot, it works perfectly (however, as I have two monitors I intend to attach, this is not a solution).

I have found the similar question on [Samsungs on support forums here](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Monitors-and-Memory/New-Samsung-monitor-won-t-connect-to-MacBook-Pro/td-p/1593128) which is unhelpfully redirected to the Business Support, where I have also raised a ticket to enquire what spec or setting results in this unique incompatibility - and if a definite answer is given, will likely look to tie several related questions together..

My questions then:

- Can this work? Is there a reason why the MBP 2014 is not able to drive a 1080p monitor from its TB2 port (but can from its HDMI)
- What could the cause of this be?

More than happy to take further questions or RFIs to try and tie up this seemingly recurring issue!

Comment: I was going to edit your "path" to put the components in the correct order because you have listed them backwards [as for some strange reason very often happens] … until I hit "HDMI/mDP Adaptor" This will not work, or it is mis-labelled. You need a MiniDP to HDMI converter. Signals go ***from*** the computer ***to*** the display.

Comment: Apologies - to clarify, I am attempting to drive the monitor *from* the computer. I listed them Left to Right in the order they are arranged on my desk and will re-order!